# Python, recursively slice dict of dicts

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

I have a dictionary of strings as keys and dictionaries as values.

```py
amount_per_feature = 2

{'first': {1231: 0.23, 8140: 0.13, 8912: 0.11, 99312: 0.52, 47833: 0.3819},
 'second': {87952: 0.933, 12031: 0.57, 10931: 0.43, 99312: 0.52},
 'third' : {23875: 0.562}
}
```

what I'm looking to achieve is to slice each dict to a certain limit. whit this example, the first list got additional item because the third dict is shorted than the specified `amount_per_feature`

```
{'first': {1231: 0.23, 8140: 0.13, 8912: 0.11},
 'second': {87952: 0.933, 12031: 0.57},
 'third' : {23875: 0.562}
}
```

But, what I really want to achieve is that if one of the dicts has less than `amount_per_feature` the leftover will be added to the slicing of the dicts that do have items.

This is how I started my approach, checking if a dict meets the limit, only if so, slice it.
but, I'm having trouble finding the recursive part which will allow me to reassign the leftovers.

```py
amount_per_feature = self.limit // len(features)
leftover = 0
tmp = {}
for feature_name, feature_values in features.items():
    feature_values = {k: v for k, v in sorted(feature_values.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])}
    tmp[feature_name] = dict(itertools.islice(feature_values.items(), amount_per_feature))
    if len(feature_values) >= amount_per_feature:
        tmp[feature_name] = dict(itertools.islice(feature_values.items(), amount_per_feature))
    else:
        leftover += amount_per_feature - len(feature_values)
```

Comment: could you post for your given example what would be the desired output?

Comment: @sambei Norimaki, updated my question

Comment: Recursion is irrelevant here because neither the data structure nor the algorithm are recursive. You should have two loops, one to count the leftover spaces and one to distribute them in whichever way that best suits your use case.